# How to compare two 3d models using forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I would like to know what is the best way to find the differences between two models loaded in memory.

The only tutorial I found was this https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/comparing-versions-viewer but in some tests I did not show all the differences between the models.

Comment: What differences specifically did the sample code miss?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial shows *how* to look for differences between two models. The sample code considers two types of changes:

- removed or added objects (based on their external IDs)
- changed properties of objects with the same external ID

And you are free to include any additional checks, for example, comparing transformation matrices or bounding boxes of objects with the same external ID, perhaps using something like [getFragmentTransform](https://petrbroz.github.io/forge-viewer-utils/master/Utilities.html#getFragmentTransform) or [getFragmentBounds](https://petrbroz.github.io/forge-viewer-utils/master/Utilities.html#getFragmentBounds).